# Check which UIElement the mouse is entering in a MouseLeave event in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, events, silverlight-4.0, mouseleave, uielement

I have two `UIElement`s next to each other that I want to behave as if they are one `MouseLeave` area.

How can I check if the mouse is over a `UIElement` being entered during a `MouseLeave` event?

Currently, checking the mouse position using the following solution shows the mouse over the element being left during the `MouseLeave` event: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/193378/448518.aspx.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the event order is deterministic, so I don't know if you can do exactly what you are describing.  You might be able to do it with some weird code.  For example, you could try making a UI element hit-test function, and checking it during the mouse leave event handler.  This would not be very flexible code.

I haven't tried this, but you could probably solve this problem by containing both UI elements in a parent element, such as a grid, and adding your event handlers to that parent.  That would be much simpler, and much more flexible.